# Is their any RAW "speech to text" English engine for Android?

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I want to convert a voice input into a raw text in English like if I say my name "Babu Somasundaram", then it should synthesis the text though this is not in dictionary.

Also is there any online services for this so that I could make a HTTP request from my Android apps if this future is not natively supported by android or any other third party APIs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try the speech recognition (and search) feature available on the home screen of almost all android phones? Every time your user wants to convert speech to text, use that service and get the text of what was said. Though, as a disclaimer, these techniques, IMHO, are very data-intensive. Hence, they would seem to work well for terms in common use, say, "Chinese eateries in SFO", but not that well for some other entries, say "Xihasdjhas" (as an example only, these are not tested).

That should be of some help.

If you want to do this yourself, there is a whole truck-load worth of literature. Type "Large vocabulary speech recognition" on Google and dive in.

HTH,
Sriram.

Comment: Thnx a lot! this will help me to move next step. :)

Comment: @Babu S: If this answer helped you, you might consider up-voting it or marking it as the correct answer.

Comment: How could I haven't done that! I tried. I'm new to Stack overflow and need more reputation to vote. Sorry for you. :( Cheers! :)